# knockout js: range slider - syntax to change attribute

Tags: knockout.js, attributes

I am working with a range slider.  The slider has an attribute sliderOptions, one of the values is for setting the maximum range.  I cannot figure out if I am doing this the right way, what is the syntax to access this element and change the "max" value after the user clicks a link?

Trying to set the value of the 'max' after a user clicks on product.

```
 <a href="#" onclick="setCategory(500)">Set Option 2</a> | <a href="#" onclick="setCategory(1000)">Set Option 2</a>
```

The function I am trying to call:

```
function setCategory(maxnum){
   /// code I am stuck on
   $('#numslider').attr('data-bind).sliderOptions("max",maxnum);
}
```

The slider element:

```
 <div class="slider" data-bind="slider: numberAmount, sliderOptions: {min: 100, max: maxVal, range: 'min', step: 10}" id="numslider"> </div>
```

The code to substantiate the slider:

//slider

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var options = allBindingsAccessor().sliderOptions || {};
    $(element).slider(options);
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slidechange", function (event, ui) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable(ui.value);
    });
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
        $(element).slider("destroy");
    });
    ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "slide", function (event, ui) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        observable(ui.value);
    });
  },
  update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    if (isNaN(value)) value = 0;
    $(element).slider("value", value);

    //console.log($(element).attr('data-bind'));
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Those bindings does not allow changing the min- or max-values. If you use the [Knockout-jQueryUI library](http://gvas.github.io/knockout-jqueryui/index.html) instead, you can easily do that though:

http://jsfiddle.net/3UvRh/

```html
<div class="slider" data-bind="slider: { value: numberAmount, min: 100, max: maxVal,
    range: 'min', step: 10}" id="numslider"></div>
```

```js
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.numberAmount = ko.observable(200);
    self.maxVal = ko.observable(500);
}

$(function () {
    var vm = new ViewModel();
    window.viewModel = vm;
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});

function setCategory(maxnum) {
    var vm = window.viewModel;
    vm.maxVal(maxnum);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks so much. does this slider have the ability to capture a slide-change event?

Comment: The `value` observable will be updated. You can [subscribe](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html#explicitly_subscribing_to_observables) to that to get notified when it changes. (In this case, it is `numberAmount`).

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally got the jQuery Mobile v1.3.1 RangeSlider to work with KnockOut

```
    //Slider event handler
    ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
        init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()); // Get the current value of the current property we're bound to
            $(element).slider();
            element.type = 'number';
            $(element).attr('data-type', 'range');
            $(element).val(valueUnwrapped).slider('refresh');
            ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function (event, ui) {
                var observable = valueAccessor();
                observable($(element).val());
            });
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
            var value = valueAccessor();
            var valueUnwrapped = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value);

            $(element).val(valueUnwrapped).slider('refresh');
        }
    };
```

And this is how you use it

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
   <div data-role="rangeslider" data-mini="true" >
     <label for="slider-Min">Label:</label>
     <input type="range" name="slider-Min" id="slider-Min" min="0" max="10000" data-bind="slider: minVal">
     <label for="slider-Max">Label:</label>
     <input type="range" name="slider-Max" id="slider-Max" min="0" max="10000" data-bind="slider: maxVal">
   </div>
</div>
```